# initramfs unpacking failed: uncompession error (debian 10)

Tags: debian, initramfs, kernel-panic

I've use debian 8-9-10 in my old Lenovo Idepan 310 without any probelem since 3 years ago, previously I also use Debian 8 in my two asus laptops without problems.

Today is my first time seeing `kernel panic` in debian. I've installed debian 10 in my new Thinkpad L390 laptop. It's been running for 1 week without any problem. But today, when I do `reboot` it failed and come to kernel panic.

The strange thing is, I didn't modify anything in the system. I just installed st terminal from luke's fork, that's it.

[image]

I've done:

1. Using `check` feature in gparted live, for sda1 partition => didn't work
2. Using `fsck` in sda1 => didn't work
3. Add init=/sbin/init in `boot/grub.cfg` => didn't work
4. Change `root=UID=....` to `root=sda1` => didn't work
5. Using chroot to do mkinitframs, can't. Mkinitframs not found, I somehow can't
   install it cause I don't have LAN lying aroung, the wifi driver is not installed
6. Removing all files/folders inside `/tmp/` => failed

All the steps above I did using gparted live cd. Because debian-10-xfce-live cd also failed to boot with the same eror message, I don't know why.

Is that because of my RAM hardware failure? I use memtest86 in garted live cd and all the test are failed. But my laptop still can run gparted live cd with no problem at all.

I do all my task since the morning (with no problem occured), I reboot it then I got this error. Why so sudden.

Thanks in advance

Note:

Even though the probability of solving it is low (and I probably reinstall the system) I want to know the cause of this, so I don't fall into the same error.

Comment: Can you successfully list (`lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-5-amd64`) your initramfs image? Can you also extract it (for example with `unmkinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-5-amd64 initramfs`)?

Comment: Even though I originally upvoted this question, I'm now voting to close it as the user has "given up" and decided to reinstall their system so the issue is no longer reproducible. Any answers are unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot an older kernel (You can choose it in grub). If this works, do a `update-initramfs -k all -c`.

Probably the last update of the initramfs aborted somehow, leaving you with a broken one.

Comment: I don't have other kernel installed (I don't do any update/upgrade). but I will try your `update-initramfs` with chroot

Comment: hint: do a `mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc` before chrooting  - and the same for dev and sys

Comment: yes, did that. I've executed your recommended command in chroot. no errors reported, just some missing firmware. rebooted, still failed.

Comment: How big is the created initrd?

Comment: I give up, because it also just age 1 week after fresh install. So I just reinstall the system. Thanks for all the help.